# Wordpress category search input

Tags: wordpress, function, search, categories, cat

I have a search function at the top of my blog however which searchs all posts.

I want to add a search function that only searches for posts within a category.

Can i use the current search  and add this to a page and tell it to display only from one category, something like

Help much appreciated.

Comment: try this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/search-results-to-show-single-category-only

Comment: `<?php get_search_form( *** use current search function but only display from cat 109);?> `